# Is "args" in Mesosphere equivalent with environment variables in docker run command?

Tags: docker, marathon, mesosphere

I have a json template for micro service to deploy using Mesosphere:

```
{
  "id": "service",
  "container": {
    "docker": {
      "image": "foo/foo:latest"
    },
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": []
  },
  "args": [
    "--key", "value"
  ],
  "cpus": 0.5,
  "mem": 128.0,
  "instances": 1
}
```

But for reasons, I want to manually do `docker run` command to deploy this container. Here's my cmd:

```
docker run --name service\
 -e "key=Mesosphere DCOS" \
 --cpu-period=100000 \
 --cpu-quota=50000 \
 --memory=128M \
 foo/foo:latest
```

Then the container exited and complained about the `key` value is missing. So I'm not sure if the `args` = `-e` in docker run command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Args" are the arguments of the command. An example is:

```
docker run --name service\
 -e "key=Mesosphere DCOS" \
 --cpu-period=100000 \
 --cpu-quota=50000 \
 --memory=128M \
 foo/foo:latest \
bash --key value
```

"Args" would be:

```
  "args": [
    "--key", "value"
  ],
```

Comment: Isn't `--` is reserved for Docker options only?

Comment: What you type after the name of the image override the definition of the command in the docker file. It is simply a shell command.